# Chain one to many `OneTimeWorkRequest` objects dynamically

Tags: android, chaining, android-workmanager

There are many ways to chain `WorkRequest` objects. Parallel, sequently and even combining multiple works.

Even though that this API seems to be very flexible, I couldn't find a way achieving the following task:

First `Worker` is responsible to gather information, at the end of its execution, it outputs a list of file names that should be manipulated. 
Afterwards, I would like to make manipulations on each of these files. 
So I would imagine having another `Worker` that is responsible to manipulate a single file. But I couldn't find a way to pipeline the output of each filename from the first `Worker` to multiple manipulator `Worker` objects. (There should be one manipulator `WorkRequest` for each of the files and these `WorkRequest` objects should run in parallel).

How can one `WorkRequest` create a dynamic number of `WorkRequest`objects based on its output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to enqueue a dynamic number of WorkRequest. The idea is that you build a chain of WorkRequests that is fixed and can be processed by WorkManager as a whole (if every worker succeeds).

For this particular case, I'll probably try create the required number of WorkRequests (one per file) when the initial WorkRequest succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can enqueue more work from inside a `Worker`. So at the end of the first `Worker` you can enqueue other workers depending on the files you want to process. You can also alternatively look at `enqueueUniqueWork()` and `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND` if you want to append to a chain of unique work.